# Is there any method to fill the combobox in winforms with all country names and another combobox with cities of the selected country?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a build procedure in C# for making a combobox or list box that has names of all countries and when a country is selected another combobox is filled with the cities of that country?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure there is a procedure.
You could start with a simple data structure:

```
public class Country
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IList<City> Cities { get; set; }

  public Country()
  {
    Cities = new List<City>();
  }
}

public class City { public string Name { get; set; } }
```

Then, instantiate this structure, e.g. into a property of your form...

```
Countries =
  new List<Country>
    {
      new Country
        {
          Name = "Germany",
          Cities =
            {
              new City {Name = "Berlin"},
              new City {Name = "Hamburg"}
            }
        },
      new Country
        {
          Name = "England",
          Cities =
            {
              new City {Name = "London"},
              new City {Name = "Birmingham"}
            }
        }
    };
```

In your form, instantiate two Binding Sources (BS):

- The first BS binds to the Countries
  property.
- The second BS binds to the first (DataSource = firstBS) and its DataMember should be "Cities".

Now you need two dropdowns:

- 1st: DataSource = first BS, DisplayMember = "Name"
- 2nd: DataSource = second BS, DisplayMember = "Name"

and you should be pretty much done.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i think it involves the manual entry of elements each time the form is loaded and it will be much of a burdon
What i was looking for was any class in c# in which it is already implemented and we could just bind the values from ther 
Regards
Mubeen

Comment: Or may be i don't know much about instantiating the structure :-S 
So can u be bit more expressive about it plzz

Comment: You have all possibilities of setting up a list of countries with a list of cities each. You could e.g. read it from DB and create the object hierarchy accordingly. Or you can populate it from an XML file. The above example is the quick'n'dirty way of ad-hoc instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such procedure. I suggest that you make a combo box and populate it with countries, and another one with cities when a country was selected. That way, you have full control over what countries and cities appear in your combo boxes.

Comment: There is some dll file in windows default folders that have this kinda  
list (some help on google search) so i wanted to know how i might use those values